# Não consigo pegar o id correto do item como parâmetro

Tags: django, django-templates

Tenho uma aplicação `django` de *posts* (postagens) e comentários de *posts*.

Nela eu posso também deletar um *post*, entretanto ao deletar um *post* a aplicação só deleta o *post* com id mais alto. O mesmo ocorre ao comentar. A aplicação só adiciona o comentário também no *post* com id mais alto.

**Model**

```
from django.db import models
from authentication.models import User

TYPE_POST = (
   ('0', 'Post'),
   ('1', 'Comment')
)

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagens/', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reactions = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    type_post = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_POST, default='0')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    commented_post = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        comments = Post.objects.filter(type_post='1', commented_post=self)

        return comments

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

**Forms**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post


class PostForm(forms.Form):
     image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
     content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)

    def is_valid(self):
         valid = super(PostForm, self).is_valid()
         image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
         content = self.cleaned_data.get('content')

        if image is None and content == '':
             self.add_error('Seu post precisa de um texto e/ou uma imagem')
             valid = False

    return valid

    def add_error(self, message):
         errors = self._errors.setdefault(forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, forms.utils.ErrorList())
         errors.append(message)

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
     content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)

def is_valid(self):
    valid = super(CommentForm, self).is_valid()
    content = self.cleaned_data.get('content')

    if content == '':
        self.add_error('Seu comentário precisa de um conteúdo')

    return valid

    def add_error(self, message):
         errors = self._errors.setdefault(forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, 
         forms.utils.ErrorList())
         errors.append(message)
```

**Trecho do Template** `index.html`

```
                                          {{ profile.full_name }}
                                </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% include 'add_post.html' %}
        {% include 'post_list.html' with posts=posts %}
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">Lado</div>
</div>
```

**View index**

```
@login_required
def index(request):
profiles = User.objects.all()
posts = Post.objects.filter(user=current_user(request), type_post='0')
paginador = Paginator(posts, 10)
page = request.GET.get('page')
posts = paginador.get_page(page)

src = {'current_user': current_user(request), 'profiles': profiles, 'form': PostForm(),
       'comment_form': CommentForm(), 'posts': posts}

return render(request, 'index.html', src)
```

**Template post_list.html**

```
{% for post in posts %}
<p>Publicado em {{ post.pub_date }}</p>
<p>{{ post.content }}</p>

<p>
    {% if post.image %}
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" style="max-width: 100%">
    {% endif %}        
</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-comment-post">Comentar</button>
<div class="modal" id="modal-comment-post" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Adicionar Comentário</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{% include 'comment_form.html' with post=post %}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% if current_user == post.user %}
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete-post">Delete</button>

    <div class="modal" id="modal-delete-post" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Excluir Postagem</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Deseja excluir a postagem?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</a>
              <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Excluir</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'report_post' post.id %}">Denunciar</a>
{% endif %}

{% for comment in post.get_comments %}
  <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
  <p>{{ comment.pub_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}

   {% endfor %}
```

**Template comment_form.html**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form action="{% url 'comment_post' post.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in comment_form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{field.label_tag }}
            {% render_field field class+="form-control" %}
        </div>
     {% endfor%}
     <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Comentar</button>
    </div>

    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        </div>
   {% endif %}
 </form>
```

**Views Delete Post e Comment Post**

```
@login_required
def delete_post(request, post_id):
post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
post.delete()

return redirect('index')

@login_required
def comment_post(request, post_id):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CommentForm(request.POST)
       post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

       if form.is_valid():
           data_form = form.cleaned_data
           Post.objects.create(content=data_form['content'], user=request.user, type_post='1', commented_post=post)

           return redirect('index')
       else:
           return redirect('index')               

       else:
          return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resover o problema, quando passei a utilizar modal para a remoção e os comentários, agora estou usando uma função JavaScript para pegar o id e passar para a modal:

```
function setPostIdDelete(postid) {
    buttonDelete = document.getElementById('delete-post');
    buttonDelete.setAttribute('href', '/posts/' + postid + '/delete/');
}


<button onclick="setPostIdDelete({{ post.id }})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete-post">Delete</button>

    <div class="modal" id="modal-delete-post" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">{% trans "Excluir Postagem" %}</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>{% trans "Deseja excluir a postagem?" %}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{% trans "Fechar" %}</a>
              <a href="" id="delete-post" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "Excluir" %}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

O mesmo, fiz para os comentários, assim consigo passar o id corretamente para a modal